# DISTINCT and LAG window function

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

There is simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE tab AS 
SELECT 1 AS t,   'G' AS company, 40 AS quote
UNION SELECT 2 , 'G',    60 
UNION SELECT 3 , 'S',    60 
UNION SELECT 4,  'S',    20;
```

And query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT company, quote ,LAG(quote) OVER(PARTITION BY company ORDER BY t)
FROM tab;
```

Output - result is consistent across RDBMSes.

```
+---------+-------+------+
| company | quote | lag  |
+---------+-------+------+
| G       |    40 | null |
| S       |    60 | null |
| G       |    60 | 40   |
| S       |    20 | 60   |
+---------+-------+------+
```

[DBFiddle Demo - PostgreSQL](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9bab6bd082147dd94f002029f659b887)

[DBFiddle Demo - SQL Server](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cfc891fb9d1271d14bb08a2d85e0a4a9)

[DBFiddle Demo - Oracle 11g](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cda28c2f6166e5b064c684b8d9066446)

[DBFiddle Demo - MariaDB](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=9bab6bd082147dd94f002029f659b887)

**[DBFiddle Demo - MySQL 8.0](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4f148fb41ea9d1a6c95718f624c60398)**

But when I try to make some calculations I get different results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT company, quote - LAG(quote) OVER(PARTITION BY company ORDER BY t)
FROM tab;
```

PostgreSQL/SQL Server/Oracle (as I expected):

```
+---------+--------+
| company | result |
+---------+--------+
| G       | null   |
| G       | 20     |
| S       | null   |
| S       | -40    |
+---------+--------+
```

MariaDB/MySQL:

```
+----------+--------+
| company  | result |
+----------+--------+
| G        | null   |
| S        | null   |
+----------+--------+
```

Now as far as I know [`Logical Query Processing`](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/07/logical-query-processing/):

> 1. FROM
> 2. ON
> 3. JOIN
> 4. WHERE
> 5. GROUP BY
> 6. WITH CUBE/ROLLUP
> 7. HAVING
> 8. SELECT
> 9. DISTINCT
>
> ...

`DISTINCT` is after `SELECT` so the correct way should be like PostgreSQL/SQL Server/Oracle.(Yes I know that I could use subquery/remove `DISTINCT` but it is not the point of the question).

Is this behaviour a bug or is it working correctly(documentation)?

Comment: Seems to be a bug in MariaDB/MySQL 8.  It even fails for `ROW_NUMBER` :-)

Comment: Also fails when you add additional rows per company, only one row with NULL is returned.

Comment: Unbelievable! Add standalone `quote` to the select list and Maria starts to understand what's going on: [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=673970cfb5aee1fe5233db092252678e). It's obviously a bug.

Comment: Your description of logical query processing is incoherent.  The main clauses of SQL do not include `ON`, `JOIN`, WITH` or `DISTINCT`.

Comment: "Unbelievable! Add standalone quote to the select list" also the case with MySQL 8.0 @klin https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xcKbWmfsmNNRmik4SN9cEd/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely a bug in both MySQL and MariaDB. I've reported the issue to the two databases, linking back to this Stack Overflow question:

- https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92503
- https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-17242

Comment: Folks folks folks. How is this not an answer? The question is: Is it a bug? And I said yes, here are the references to the bug reports. Relax, people :-) (if this is not an answer, then there cannot be any answer at all)

Comment: @LukasEder Thanks for  your input. I should have reported bug  myself. Btw could you take a look at [Oracle -returning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52337932/oracle-returning-combined-with-aggregate-functions)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda: You reported it here, which has already helped quite a few people! I'm sorry about that Oracle thing, don't know the background. Seems like something only an Oracle engineer could answer